# application/octet-stream в png

Tags: php, fileupload

На сервер приходят *.png файлы как `application/octet-stream`, сохраняю:

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$varname]['tmp_name'][$key], $dir . $name);`

Но потом они не открываются, как сразу при сохранении их декодировать в нормальный формат?

Для отправки, файлы собираются таким образом:

```
const fileBlob = document.querySelector('#submitAttachments');
const reader = new FileReader();
const file = reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileBlob);
const files = [new Uint8Array(file)];
```

Comment: Что значит «не открываются»?

Comment: Откуда вы знаете что это PNG?

Comment: "Не открываются" - It looks like we don’t support this file format

Comment: PNG - Потому что отправляю PNG

Comment: fileBlob - это input ? с multi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file_put_contents($dir . $name, pack("c*", ...explode(',', file_get_contents($dir . $name))));
```